# The best LaTeX distribution in 2019 for macOS?

Tags: distributions

Is *MacTeX* the best all-arounder LaTeX distribution at the moment or is it better to use *MiKTeX*, *TexLive* or something else that I don't even know.

I'm looking mostly for an easy to install/uninstall distribution that won't need addition memory while operating (cache, etc.) with a decent level of support.

Thanks :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). If you are not concered about disk space definetly use MacTeX (which is a TeXLive distribution).

Comment: Mactex is also the easiest to install (needs updating afterwards though)

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much. So, I'm gonna stick with MacTeX as usual.